# Can we do push notification using phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am wrapping currently developed RWD website into phonegap plugin .  Basically it is hybrid approach.  we don't have much native requirement except push notification. Can push notification is achievable using phonegap plugin?  or Do I need to write complete app in phonegap.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible, and it works very well

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push